# Top-down movement

Tags: java, adventure-game

I've been working on a Final Fantasy-ish game and am leaning toward more like 1 - 3. This is my attempt at map movement. It does work, but if anyone has any suggestions or critiques, I would like to hear them. For instance, is there a different way you would do something or is there a way I can clean up the code?

```
package com.stardust.main;

import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.KeyListener; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player implements KeyListener 
{ 
    //Location
    private int x, y; 
    //Size Variables 
    private int sx, sy; 
    //Movement tests 
    public boolean up = false, dn = false, lt = false, rt = false;       
    public int SPEED = 3; 
    //More movement test mToPMove() stands for map to player movement up, down, left, right 
    private boolean mToPMoveU = false, mToPMoveD = false, mToPMoveL = false, mToPMoveR = false;

    public BufferedImage image;

    public Player(int x, int y, int sx, int sy, BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sx = sx;
        this.sy = sy;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        //here map moves because player is in center of map
        if(up && !mToPMoveU)
        {
          Game.getnewBackground().y += SPEED;          
        }
        if(dn && !mToPMoveD)
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().y -= SPEED;
        }
        if(lt && !mToPMoveL)
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().x += SPEED;
        }
        if(rt & !mToPMoveR)
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().x -= SPEED;
        }
        //check when map hits edges of frame, then start player movement
        checkMapPosition();
        if(up && mToPMoveU)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().y -= SPEED;
        }
        if(dn && mToPMoveD)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().y += SPEED;
        }
        if(lt && mToPMoveL)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().x -= SPEED;
        }
        if(rt && mToPMoveR)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().x += SPEED;
        }
        //check when player hits edge of map
        checkPlayerPosition();
        //when player gets back to the center of the map, start map movement again
        reverseMove();

    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, sx, sy, null);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            up = true;            
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            dn = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            lt = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            rt = true;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            dn = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            lt = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            rt = false;
        }
    }

    public void checkMapPosition()
    {
        if(Game.getnewBackground().y >= 0)
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().y = 0;
            mToPMoveU = true;
            mToPMoveD = true;
        }
        if(Game.getnewBackground().y <= Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() - (Game.getnewBackground().sy + 30))
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().y = Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() - (Game.getnewBackground().sy + 30);
            mToPMoveD = true;
            mToPMoveU = true;
        }
        if(Game.getnewBackground().x >= 0)
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().x = 0;
            mToPMoveL = true;
            mToPMoveR = true;
        }
        if(Game.getnewBackground().x <= Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() - (Game.getnewBackground().sx))
        {
            Game.getnewBackground().x = Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() - (Game.getnewBackground().sx);
            mToPMoveR = true;
            mToPMoveL = true;
        }

    }

    public void checkPlayerPosition()
    {
        if(Game.getPlayer().y <= 0)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().y = 0;
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().y >= Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() - ((Game.getPlayer().sy * 2) - 4))
        {
            Game.getPlayer().y = Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() - ((Game.getPlayer().sy * 2) - 4);
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().x <= 0)
        {
            Game.getPlayer().x = 0;
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().x >= Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() - (Game.getPlayer().sx - 2))
        {
            Game.getPlayer().x = Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() - (Game.getPlayer().sx - 2);
        }

    }

    public void reverseMove()
    {
        if(Game.getPlayer().y == Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() / 2 && mToPMoveU && mToPMoveD)
        {
           mToPMoveD = false;
           mToPMoveU = false;
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().y == Game.getFrameSize().getHeight() / 2 && mToPMoveD && mToPMoveU)
        {
            mToPMoveU = false;
            mToPMoveD = false;
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().x == Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() / 2 && mToPMoveL && mToPMoveR)
        {
            mToPMoveL = false;
            mToPMoveR = false;
        }
        if(Game.getPlayer().x == Game.getFrameSize().getWidth() / 2 && mToPMoveR && mToPMoveL)
        {
            mToPMoveR = false;
            mToPMoveL = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The first thing I noticed is that you're lacking [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Why does you `Player` class implement `KeyListener`? It should just represent the state of your player in the game **without** dealing with user input. That should be the concern of another class.

Why do you have `public int SPEED = 3;`? You should really pass this a parameter to the constructor (or to a modifier method). Public fields are almost always a bad idea. You usually don't want them so you can have a better control of who/how can modify them.

`mToPMoveU`, `mToPMoveD`, `mToPMoveL`, and `mToPMoveR` have a very poor naming. What about introducing an `enum MoveDirection` with `Up`, `Down`, `Left`, `Right`, (and maybe `None`)? That should help you make your code cleaner.

Why is `image` a public member?

What is the meaning of `sx` and `sy`? Their naming is cryptic and does not help me understand what is their purpose.

All the invocation to static methods in `Game` like `Game.getnewBackground().y` are a huge smell. Why do you need them? You should avoid almost at all static methods.
Probably what you need is an `public Movement update()` method, that returns information about the movement performed by the player. It should be called by `Game`, which should also compute the new position regarding the current background. It does not make much sense to have it in `Player`. Ditto for `checkMapPosition`, `checkPlayerPosition`, and `reverseMove` invocations.

You want a different class to handle input and rendering. That class should contain the `render`, `keyTyped`, `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` methdods. They clearly don't belong to `Player`.

I hope that these comments will give you some ideas on how to structure better your code.

Comment: I just wrote an answer containing exactly the same points, so instead of posting it just a quick addition: `dn`, `lt`, `rt` could also be better named, as could `checkPlayerPosition`, which doesn't just check the position, it also corrects it, and `reverseMove`, which doesn't really reverse a move.

Comment: Well thank you both for the suggestions. I was planning on putting most of that code in it's own class, this was mostly a test to see if i could get it working. One thing though, if I'm not supposed to use static methods to get the background and player, how am I supposed to move them?

Comment: You should have a `Game` class that holds references to instances of `Player` class. `Game` should know the status of the world and of the background. It should also take care of the update cycle. In `Game.update()` you need to call `Player.update()` and you have two ways to implement it. In the first you should obtain from it an object representing the movement and have `Game` process it. Alternatively you can pass the state of the world as a parameter to `Player.update(state)` and let it update its internal state. I think that the first solution is cleaner than the second.

Comment: I do have a Game class that is the main logic of the program. So do you mean that if I call the movement object in Game that I won't need the static methods? Or do I use the variables I was using as parameters for the movement object?

Comment: Well, I think that it depends a bit on the game you are implementing and on what you need to do. As far as I understood your requirements, you probably need a `Player` class that holds information about the player. In this case I think we are only interested in its speed. Then you need a `Game` class that needs to keep track of the state of the world and another class that process inputs form the user. When you get an input from the user, you need to call an `Update(action)` method on `Game`. Action is something like `MoveLeft`, `MoveRight`, and so on.

Comment: Within `Game.Update` you need to figure out how you need to move the player. So you need a `Movement Player.Move(action)` method that returns a `Movement` object. You can imagine it as a simple object containing an `(dx,dy)` pair. Your game class needs to take `dx` and `dy` values and update the position of the player and the state of everything else accordingly. As you see, `Player` only knows how it moves (basically how fast it is) and does **not** know anything else about the state of the game, which pertains to the `Game` class

Comment: So I've updated my code. Now do I edit this post to the new code or do I post an entirely new question?

Comment: Write a follow up question. If you change this one the answers you get will become meaningless. Make sure you link this question in the new one you create so it will be easier to track your progress